# Change alphabet when select radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click one of the alphabet, the selected one shall be displayed and the rest should be hidden.

Somehow, the code doesn't work. I'm using jQuery.

```js
$("#r-learn-more").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});

$("#r-book-viewing").click(function() {
  $("#bb").attr("display", "block");
});

$("#r-closing-price").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fieldset-content">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="one" name="radiogroup1" id="r-learn-more" checked="">
    <label for="r-learn-more">a</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="two" name="radiogroup1" id="r-book-viewing">
    <label for="r-book-viewing">b</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="three" name="radiogroup1" id="r-closing-price">
    <label for="r-closing-price">c</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="aa" style="display: block;">a</div>
<div id="bb" style="display: none;">b</div>
<div style="display: none;">c</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you tried with `$("#bb").attr('display','block')`, must be `$("#bb").css("display","block");`

Maybe the better way is to use something like:

```
<div class="fieldset-content">
   <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" data-show="aa" value="one" name="radiogroup1" id="r-learn-more" checked="">
      <label for="r-learn-more">a</label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" data-show="bb" value="two" name="radiogroup1" id="r-book-viewing">
      <label for="r-book-viewing">b</label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" data-show="cc" value="three" name="radiogroup1" id="r-closing-price">
      <label for="r-closing-price">c</label>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="aa" class='item' style="display: block;">a</div>
<div id="bb" class='item' style="display: none;">b</div>
<div id="cc" class='item' style="display: none;">c</div>
```

And JS

```
var $items = $('.item');
$(':radio').on('change', function () {
   var $item = $('#' + this.dataset.show);

   $items.not($item).css('display', 'none');
   $item.css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('.radio input').change(function(event){
    $('.alphabet-letter').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).data('id')).show();
}).first().prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-content">

  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="one" name="radiogroup1" id="r-learn-more" data-id="aa">
    <label for="r-learn-more">a</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="two" name="radiogroup1" id="r-book-viewing"  data-id="bb">
    <label for="r-book-viewing">b</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" value="three" name="radiogroup1" id="r-closing-price"  data-id="cc">
   <label for="r-closing-price">c</label>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="aa" class="alphabet-letter">
a
</div>

<div id="bb" class="alphabet-letter">
b
</div>

<div id="cc" class="alphabet-letter">
c
</div>
```

Comment: When i have selected a then i also would like to to select c or a. The radio button of a, b and c should always be visible.

Comment: Hopefully that’s what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't even be easier just to have one "result" div?

Something like this

EDIT: For displaying the "a" as default either you just put "a" in the result div, or maybe on load you get the text (in this case you are not using the value) of the radio button option selected as per the edit in the snippet

```js
$('#result').text($('input:radio[name=radiogroup1]:checked').parent().text());
$( ".radio input" ).click(function() {
var label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']");
  console.log(label);
  console.log(label.html());
  $('#result').text(label.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-content">

  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="one" name="radiogroup1" id="r-learn-more" checked="">
    <label for="r-learn-more">a</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" value="two" name="radiogroup1" id="r-book-viewing">
    <label for="r-book-viewing">b</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" value="three" name="radiogroup1" id="r-closing-price">
   <label for="r-closing-price">c</label>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="result" style="display: block;">
<!--Alernative to load the text by jquery you could just put here "a"-->
</div>
```

Comment: when you have a as a default, you also should display the value "a" below.

Comment: @HelloWorld, then just initialize it as "a" as per the edit. I still think is cleaner

Comment: Even more, you can just get the value (in your case text) of the one selected on load